Magento 2 Layer Navigation filters for Configurable Products Variations
In my magento 2 store only configurable products are visible. The simple products are associated at configurable products and basically they have one or two attributes for variations. Specifically they have size and color. In Layer navigation i have filters for size and color.
My main problem is that when a user filters with with a combination of attributes the result he will get will be all configurable products that have a match to at least one of these attributes and not in the combination.
For example imagine that i have a the following Products :

ProductA with ProductA1(Size=5,Color=6) and ProductA2(Size=6,Color=8)
ProductB with ProductB1(Size=5,Color=7) and ProductB1(Size=6,Color=6)
ProductC with ProductC1(Size=5,Color=7) and ProductC1(Size=6,Color=8)

Filters Applied are Size=5 and Color=6
My expected result is ProductA
Instead i get both ProductA and ProductB.
So if a customer that is searching for the combination of Size=5 and Color=6 when he will click ProductB he will find that this combination does not exist in that product.
Is there any solution for that ??
Any help is appreciated!
